# How to I disable the "@" mentions message input component in GetStream on my Messaging App?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, getstream-io, tsx

I want to disable the @ ability on an app for the time being, or just be able to edit the way it looks, that would also work. I can't seem to find a place in the code I am looking on the React Native project for doing this, and I cannot see an ability to get rid of it on the GetStream dashboard as well nor its documentation.

What can I do to change what I am seeing with the @ messages chat function on GetStream? Thanks for any help, I am new to GetStream messaging apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the mentions (and other autocomplete input) with the [`autoCompleteTriggerSettings` setting on the channel level](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/sdk/reactnative/guides/message-input-customization/#disable-autocomplete-features-on-input-mentions-and-commands).

```
<Channel
  autoCompleteTriggerSettings={() => ({})}
  ...
>
```